# Nuxt serverMiddleware always return 200 code

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to handle request errors on the ssr side, for this I use serverMiddleware, but the problem is that res.statusCode is always 200. Although in the browser I see the page crashed with 500 code. Feeling as if the middleware fires before my api requests. Is there any way to solve this problem?

`server-middleware/logger.js`

```
export default function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Server middleware', res.statusCode);
  next()
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
serverMiddleware: ['~/server-middleware/logger'],
```

Comment: Do we agree that `serverMiddleware` is run only once? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#server Or do you have `target: server` (default)?

Comment: @kissu i dont have target prop in nuxt config and serverMiddleware run on every page redirect/reload

Comment: Yep, so you're using the defautl: `server`. Yes, this is indeed used on each reload. Not sure what you do mean by redirect, but yeah it's only when the server side page is requested, then on client side, it will never be called again, so that we are on the same page here. What are the log of the `500` code?

Comment: @kissu it doesn't matter if the request falls on the server side or returns without errors (401, 404, 500), I always get res.statusCode = 200 in the middleware anyway. Because of this, I get a problem that I can't handle errors at the ssr stage to do redirect to 500.vue page

Comment: Why would you get anything else than a `200` in the `logger` middleware so far? When is your possible `500` hapening. When the server side page is sent or on the client? If it's on the server, you have some real issues into serving your app so far.